# React onClick button is not triggering the function

Tags: reactjs

I am developing an chrome extension where i need to authentication user but a very simple onClick button which calls a function is not working
this is the simple code where i want to show info on console when button is clicked

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Login = () => {
    const [user, setuser] = useState("");
    const handleSubmit = (data) => {
        data.preventDefault();
        console.log("usernae: ");
        console.log("Data: ", data.target);
    }
    const getInputValue = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        // Select input element and get its value
        console.log("I am heresdfg")
        //   let inputVal = document.getElementsByClassName("usernameInputField")[0].value;
        //   Display the value
        //   alert(inputVal);
    }
    return (

        <div
            id="login-form">
            <p>
                <div className='form'>
                    
                </div>
                <input type="text"
                    id="username"
                    name="username"
                    className='usernameInputField'
                    value={user}
                    onChange={(event => setuser(event.target.value))}
                    placeholder="Username" required />
            </p>

            <p>

                <button onClick={getInputValue} type="button" id="login">button</button>

            </p>

        </div>
    );
};
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the **input value** value inside the event handler if I'm not wrong, you can get it from the state - `user` as

```
 const getInputValue = (event) => {
        console.log(user)
    }
```

as the `event` would be `button`'s you wouldn't get the value of `input` from it's event and it is not required too as it's already in the react's state ....

## Example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
  
    const submitHandler = () => {
      console.log(name)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            Name: <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}/>
            <button onClick={submitHandler}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think onClick does not hit the method if I console.log("here") it will still show nothing on the console.

Comment: It will show ... let me update with a working sample ..

Answer (score 0):

In the `getInputValue` function event is pointing to the button.
Change the `event.target.value` to `user` if you want to print the text into the console.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/onclick-cz1mum?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

If you don't want to use the value from `useState` then you can also check [useRef](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp) hook which works in a similar way.